# Implementing ACL with webhooks for VerneMQ

Tags: caching, mqtt, webhooks

I am trying to get ACL behavior by implementing my own webhooks for VerneMQ. I am using `express` and `apicache` node packages for this. I hope the code is meaningful to non-javascript-programmers as well.

In my `vernemq.conf` I have set up my hooks, and they get called correctly:

```
$ vmq-admin webhooks show
+-----------------+------------------------------+-------------+
|      hook       |           endpoint           |base64payload|
+-----------------+------------------------------+-------------+
|auth_on_subscribe|http://127.0.0.1:3000/vmq/sub |    true     |
|auth_on_register |http://127.0.0.1:3000/vmq/auth|    true     |
| auth_on_publish |http://127.0.0.1:3000/vmq/pub |    true     |
+-----------------+------------------------------+-------------+
```

Also I disabled all other plugins and disabled anonymous login.

My webhooks implementation in `express` (simplified):

```js
const express = require('express');
const apicache = require('apicache');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

// short cache times for demonstration
const authcache = apicache.middleware('15 seconds');
const pubcache = apicache.middleware('5 seconds');
const subcache = apicache.middleware('10 seconds');

const app = express();

const jsonparser = bodyparser.json();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`${req.connection.remoteAddress}:${req.connection.remotePort} ${req.method} ${req.path}`);
    return next();
});

app.post('/vmq/auth', authcache, (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json({result: 'ok'});
});

app.post('/vmq/pub', pubcache, jsonparser, (req, res) => {
    // this gets ignored most of the time because of caching
    if (req.body.topic === 'only/allowed/topic') {
        return res.status(200).json({result: 'ok'});
    }
    return res.status(401).end();
});

app.post('/vmq/sub', subcache, (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json({result: 'ok'});
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(404).end();
});

app.use((err, res, req, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).end();
});

const server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    return console.log(`listening on ${address.address}:${address.port} ...`);
});
```

Using `mqtt.js` I wrote a client (simplified):

```js
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');

client.on('connect', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        client.publish('only/allowed/topic', 'working');
        client.publish('some/disallowed/topic', 'working too :(');
    }, 500);
    return client.subscribe('some/disallowed/topic');
});

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
   return console.log(`${topic}:${message}`); 
});
```

What happens is that the client successfully authenticates and then publishes to `only/allowed/topic`, which is allowed and gets cached as successful by VerneMQ. However, since the successful call to `/vmq/pub` is now cached, publishing to `some/disallowed/topic` also works. If I change the order of publishing, both will fail.

I would have expected VerneMQ to map the cached results to all parameters in a call, except the payload of course, and not just to a client connection. However that is not the case. **What's a possible way to implement ACL via webhooks while using caching?** Not using caching is out of the question, as this kills my performance, and caching is recommended by the docs anways.

Also, will someone with 1500+ rep be so nice and create the tag `vernemq`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood how `apicache` works and what it actually does. All I needed to do was just setting the appropriate header for caching, as stated in the docs of VerneMQ. Apparently `apicache` stores the actual result and returns that whenever asked within the specified timeframe, no matter what the client is actually requesting.

This is the working code now:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// short cache times for demonstration (in seconds)
const authcachetime = 15;
const pubcachetime = 5;
const subcachetime = 10;

const jsonparser = bodyparser.json();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`${req.connection.remoteAddress}:${req.connection.remotePort} ${req.method} ${req.path}`);
    return next();
});

app.post('/vmq/auth', (req, res) => {
    res.set('cache-control', `max-age=${authcachetime}`);
    return res.status(200).json({result: 'ok'});
});

app.post('/vmq/pub', jsonparser, (req, res) => {
    res.set('cache-control', `max-age=${pubcachetime}`);
    if (req.body.topic === 'only/allowed/topic') {
        return res.status(200).json({result: 'ok'});
    }
    return res.status(401).end();
});

app.post('/vmq/sub', (req, res) => {
    res.set('cache-control', `max-age=${subcachetime}`);
    return res.status(200).json({result: 'ok'});
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(404).end();
});

app.use((err, res, req, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).end();
});

const server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    return console.log(`listening on ${address.address}:${address.port} ...`);
});
```

As expected the client now gets an error when it tries to publish to an illegal topic.